# DRF MultiPartParser returns value as list

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an API endpoint. Here I am using `MultiPart/form-data` content-type to cater multiple input types. But I am stuck in `MultiPartParser`.

my view function declaration is something like this:

```
@api_view(['GET','POST','PUT'])
@parser_classes([MultiPartParser,JSONParser])
def item_view(request):
```

The `MultiPartParser` is parsing this:

```
<QueryDict: {'code': ['3'], 'gst_rate': ['5']}> <MultiValueDict: {}>
```

What I want:

```
<QueryDict: {'code':3, 'gst_rate':5}> <MultiValueDict: {}>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't because of `MultiPartParser`. Even if you are just using e.g. `JSONParser`, the value will still be a list because query parameters are string based, thus there can be duplicates.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/some_random_api4/?code=3&gst_rate=5&code=7
```

Here, the query string is `?code=3&gst_rate=5&code=7`. We can see that there are 2 values for the same field `code`, which are `"3"` and `"7"`.

**Code**

```
print(f"{request.query_params=}")
for param_name in request.query_params.keys():
    print(param_name)
    print("\t", request.query_params.getlist(param_name))
    print("\t", request.query_params.get(param_name))
    print(f"\t {request.query_params[param_name]=}")
```

**Output**

```
request.query_params=<QueryDict: {'code': ['3', '7'], 'gst_rate': ['5']}>
code
     request.query_params.getlist(param_name)=['3', '7']
     request.query_params.get(param_name)='7'
     request.query_params[param_name]='7'
gst_rate
     request.query_params.getlist(param_name)=['5']
     request.query_params.get(param_name)='5'
     request.query_params[param_name]='5'
```

Here, we can see that the `QueryDict` reflects the list of codes `"3"` and `"7"` as with the `getlist()` operation, while the the `get()` and `[]` (`__getitem__()`) only gets the one value, here being the last which is `"7"`.

Instead of manually calling `get()` or `[]` or `items()` on the `QueryDict`, we can simply use [dict()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.dict) (unless you want to change the implementation to get the first value in the list instead of the last):

**Code**

```
query_params_updated = request.query_params.dict()
print(f"{query_params_updated=}")
```

**Output**

```
query_params_updated={'code': '7', 'gst_rate': '5'}
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I updated my answer to simplify the process with the use of [QueryDict.dict()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.dict). Hope it fits you well :)

Comment: Of course the updated answers simplifies a lot.